# Encrypt Request/Reponse in MVC4 WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a old api that receives an encrypted request and encrypts the response once complete.  I am attempting to switch this to mvc4 webapi and it has gone smooth until I hit this encryption. What I need is a way to decrypt the request when it comes in so mvc will act on it properly. Also once the process is complete encrypt the response before sending it.  I do not want to place the encryption parts in each action.

Note:
The body is still properly formatted as a single item, so I would push it all through a single action with a selector of my own, but would prefer a more proper rest style implementation.

Comment: Is the decrypting/encrypting some kind of legacy functionality because SSL would be a better technique for this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a MessageHandler.  There are a bunch of examples of how to create MessageHandlers in [WebAPIContrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/tree/master/src/WebApiContrib/MessageHandlers)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own model binder

```
public class DecObjModelBinder : IModelBinder
{   


  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
      ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
    //make a instance of your object
    var myObj = new DecObj()

    //bind the properties from my obj

    myObj.Title= bindingContext
        .ValueProvider
        .GetValue("Title") // The Property name sent from the browser
        .ToString();

    /* then the property you want to decrypt */
    var encBody = bindingContext
        .ValueProvider
        .GetValue("EncBody") // The Property name sent from the browser
        .ToString();

    /* decryption logic here to the encBody then after assign the decrypted value to myObj*/

    return myObj;
   }
```

and then You register the `ModelBinder` in Global.asx in Application_Start via: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DecObj), new  DecObjModelBinder());`

Comment: This is too late in the process. The action is already selected. I do not want every action to accept the DecObj. I was hoping to get to the request really early the process before the action was selected.

Comment: the `ActionInvoker` is responsible for invoking the action its way early in the pipeline for it to be responsible for the action parameters after the `ActionInvoker` invokes the action the `ModelBinder` do its job then the filters so the `ModelBinder` is the first thing responsible for reading the data and bind them