# ASP .NET Web API reading inputstream twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP .NET Web API and I have a Controller that have code similar to this:

```
[Route("UpdateData")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateData([FromBody]RequestClasses.UpdataData data)
{
    string json;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
        {
            json = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    // Dencrypt json

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

As input parameter I have "[FromBody]RequestClasses.UpdataData data". I have this in order to be able to show a Help page (using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage).

The data object received in this method is encrypted and I need to decrypt it.

My problem is that I cannot call HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream because the "[FromBody]RequestClasses.UpdataData data" has disposed my InputStream.

Any good ideas to solve this? As I still need the help page to show which parameters to call the method with.

Comment: Why NOT just remove the parameter?

Comment: Because the parameter is the one that gives me a help page that show which json object to send to the method. Maybe there is another way to make Web API help page generate this. That is implecit part of my question

Comment: You can remove the parameter, then build it while reading the InputStream. In this way you can have both things, but the drawback is, you have to perform de-serialization on your own.

Comment: Why are you manually encrypting data that you send like that? -- This is literally what SSL (i.e. HTTPS) was designed to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

By design ASP.NET Web API can only read the payload input stream once. So, if the parameter binder reads it, you don't have it available. That's way people is telling you in the comments to use parameterless methods, and read the payload yourself.

However, you want to have parameters to see them in the help page. There is a solution for that: do the decryption of the request in previous steps. To do that you can use Message handlers. Please, see this: [Encrypt Request/Reponse in MVC4 WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074507/encrypt-request-reponse-in-mvc4-webapi)